# Unable to get the look-up column value using JSOM

Tags: jsom, spfieldlookupvalue

I am trying to get the value of SharePoint lookup column with below both the options.But I am finding no luck with it.

Can any one please help me what's the issue.

```
var TabletopSessionsvalue=oListItem.get_item("TabletopSessions").get_lookupValue();
 or
var TabletopSessionsvalue=oListItem.get_item("TabletopSessions")
var lookupvalue=TabletopSessionsvalue.get_lookupValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

var TabletopSessionsvalue= item.get_item('TabletopSessions');
    var TabletopLabel = TabletopSessionsvalue.get_lookupValue();
    var TabletopId = TabletopSessionsvalue.get_lookupId();
Here **TabletopSessions** must be internal name of the lookup column and must be single lookup.

For multi lookup

```
//Get Multiple Lookup Field value
var TabletopSessionsvalue= item.get_item('TabletopSessions'); 
for(var i = 0; i < TabletopSessionsvalue.length; i++) {
var TabletopLabelValue = TabletopSessionsvalue[i];
var TabletopLabel= TabletopLabelValue.get_lookupValue();
var TabletopId= TabletopLabelValue.get_lookupId();
}
```